# How can I make my android app more memory efficient and faster

Tags: android

Can anyone give me few tips and also few links to follow  so that i can make my android app more memory efficient and faster.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your situation and how your app is built, there is no right or wrong answer, but this documentation can give you some good guidelines http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

For memory leaks take a look at traceview http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html